# Choices-js select list is returning an array

Tags: javascript, choices.js

i'm using **choices-js select list** and it's value is being an array like this

```
array:1 [▼ // app\Http\Livewire\Admin\Users\UserForm.php:56
  "value" => "male"
]
```

and this is my select list

```
<select class="form-control" name='gender' id="choices-gender">
    <option value="">Seç</option>
    <option value="male">Erkek</option>
    <option value="female">Kadın</option>
</select>
```

```
<script src="/assets/js/plugins/choices.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const gender = document.getElementById('choices-gender');
    if (gender) {
        const example = new Choices(gender);
    }
</script>
```

I don't want the value to be an array, how can just get the value?

Comment: What should it be then?

Comment: so does the library you are using have documentation?

Comment: how the way are u sending the value ?

Comment: it should be just a key and a value like any select list @Wimanicesir

Comment: yes this is it https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices but i didn't find anything to solve it @epascarello

Comment: https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices#getvaluevalueonly shows it returns an array so read the first index...

Comment: Read the documentation and use the method that produce the output closest to your needs. You can always process the output to more suit your needs if it does not already. No library will produce exactly what you want out of the box.